# htaccess parameter to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect this

```
http://www.domain.com/test.php?sub=subdomain&type=cars
```

redirects to

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/cars
```

I already have mod_rewrite rules to do the opposite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/index.php?route=$1&name=%1 [R=301,L]
```

with htaccess ,help me plz...

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of 'subdomain' and 'cars' off the query string you need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

I don't know for sure but you could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.)\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sub=(.*)&type=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.) http://$2.$1.com/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for rapid respons but does not work

Comment: ugh, i tried to figure it out but no luck, sorry!